# Expected expression before '%' token in if condition

Tags: c, expression, token

I was corious about learning just C language and I am getting mistake which makes me stucked at one smiley point :-) .

```
int lowest() {
    int c1,c2,c3,min;

    printf("Type three integer numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&c1, &c2, &c3);

    if ((c1 < c2) %% (c1 < c3)) { // SOMWHERE HERE IS MISTAKE
        min = c1;
        printf("Lowest from %d, %d, %d is %d", c1,c2,c3, min);
    } else if ((c2 < c1) %% (c2 < c3)) {
        min = c2;
        printf("Lowest from %d, %d, %d is %d", c1,c2,c3, min);
    } else {
        min = c3;
        printf("Lowest from %d, %d, %d is %d", c1,c2,c3, min);
    }

}
```

function is called in another main function.

Comment: What is your exact error message? Actually, the '%%' looks wrong; this should probably be either '&&' (and) or '||' (or).

Comment: C does not have `%%` operator. You need to read about logical operators https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-logical-operators?view=vs-2019

Comment: `%` is right next to `&` on most keyboards, so I suspect this is a simply typo (and you meant `&&` instead of `%%`). If this is not a typo, then you really need to think about what you're doing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is not next. There is a `$` \between and he has repeated it twice. Hard to believe in typo.

Comment: @P__J__ on my keyboard (German layout) the keys are `$%&`, i.e. `%` is next to `&`. Not sure about layout in Slowakia.

Comment: I use only english keyboard and sorry there is `^` between.

Comment: What we really need now is some clarification from the OP. @xhalajs please respond. Please don't post and abandon for a lengthy period.

Comment: accept the answer if it solves your problem!

Answer (score 2):

Either you have gotten the syntax wrong, or it is an innocent typo. Either way the error comes from

> `if ((c1 < c2) %% (c1 < c3)) { // SOMWHERE HERE IS MISTAKE`

Specifically, `%%` is not an operator.

[**Logical operators in C**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_logical_operators.htm)

A short explanation of the three **Logical**  operators:

### Logical **AND** operator: `&&`

```c
//   (7 > 0 && 6 > 0) == true
//   (7 > 0 && 6 < 0) == false
```

If both the conditions are `true`, it returns `true`. Otherwise, it returns `false`

### Logical **OR** operator: `||`

```c
//   (7 > 0 || 6 > 0) == true
//   (7 > 0 || 6 < 0) == true
//   (7 < 0 || 6 < 0) == false
```

If either of the conditions is `true`, it returns `true`. Otherwise, it returns false.

### Logical operator **NOT**: `!`

The `!` operator just reverses the expression. For example,

```c
// !true == false
// !(any true statement) == false
// !(any false statement) == true

// (!(6 < 0)) == true
// (!(6 > 0)) == false
```

I believe you have intended to use the logical `&&` operator. If so correct it and there won't be any more errors. So the correct **expression** should be

```
if ((c1 < c2) && (c1 < c3)) {
   //Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably typed `%%` as a mistake. There are 3 operators in C language these are:

1. `&&` (AND Operator)
2. `||` (OR Operator)
3. `!` (NOT Operator)

Sometimes I type `%%` instead of `&&` as a mistake. Be aware of these small syntax mistakes.